# Alfresco apply category with js to doc

Tags: javascript, alfresco

How to apply category to document in Alfresco with javascript?

tried like this:

```
document.properties["cm:categories"] = "testCat";
```

UPDATE:

like this I am able to get "root categories" but not "sub categories":

```
var rootCats =  classification.getRootCategories("cm:generalclassifiable");
document. properties["cm:categories"] = rootCats[3];
```

this doesnt work:

```
document. properties["cm:categories"] = rootCats[3][1];
```

Comment: RootCats.children gives you what?

Comment: can't see it, can't debugg it :( but eg rootCats[3] gave me "firstLvlCat" (root Category) so i gues rootCats is array of root categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out, if someone need it this is the way how it cana be done

get all root categories [audio, video, image, ...]

```
var rootCats =  classification.getRootCategories("cm:generalclassifiable");
```

get subcategories from desired  root category -> sub category from "video" [horror, comedy, ...]

```
var singleCat = rootCats[1].subCategories;
```

apply category to document -> apply "horror" to document

```
doc. properties["cm:categories"] = singleCat[0]; //app
```

save it

```
doc.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the document has the aspect classifiable (ie having the cm:generalClassifiable aspect).

Then look up the category you want to add ie:

UPDATE: an example query to find a node of type category of a certain name:

Search for your category like this for example, you could add a PATH clause as well to be sure your in the right hierarchy.

`var nodes = var categories= search.luceneSearch('+TYPE:"http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}category" +@name:testCat');`

then get the element out of the returned array...

Get the existing categories for the node:

`categories= document.properties["cm:categories"];`

Push the new category onto the array:

`categories.push(categoryToAdd);`

Assign this to the document:

`document.properties["cm:categories"] = categories;`

`document.save();`

Comment: it doesnt work like that, it says `Invalid node ref - does not contain forward slash: testCat`, yep, that cat exist

Comment: Sorry for beeing too fast in my answer. The cm:categories property contains an array of nodeRef:s pointing to every assigned category. So you will need to look up the node of the category you want to assign and then add it to the existing array property.

Comment: how categoryToAdd shoould look like, structure?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement, and although slightly different to OP question, it is close enough to warrant inclusion here we feel.

We occasionally have a need to bulk apply categories. ie:new business acquired, migrate all their docs in, add categories to match existing content.

Adding categories to large numbers of documents is tedious in the interface. It needs to enable the aspect (classifiable), then edit properties to select the categories required. For every document individually.  Worse, the add aspect isn't available for documents from the explorer view in share, so entering the preview is required.  For large docs, entering the preview is itself a few more seconds delay.

So we built a simple script that applies the categories of the **parent folder** to everything placed under it. Then we only need to set the categories of that folder and start moving content through it (ie:move content in to obtain the category/ies, then move back to where it came, but now all have aspect and category/ies applied).

Actually we have 2 at the moment:

1. The first folder/rule overrides whatever categories the objects had and
   replaces them with just those from the parent folder - we name this folder BulkCategorise
2. The 2nd is cumulative, so it keeps existing categories and only
   adds those from the parent folder, which we name AccumulateCategories

We will create a third to selectively remove them when time permits.

A couple of notes:

- adding the classifiable aspect is not actually required to be done
  manually or in code, it "Just Works" - at least in 5.1.
- this may not be the best way to do this
- accumulating a category that is already applied doesn't appear to cause any issues, they appear to coalesce/merge automatically

To use these scripts, create 2 folders and apply a rule to each to run the associated script.

The 1st script completely replaces the categories of the object with those of the parent folder and is trivially simple [Set the @name and SITE to match your installation]:

```
var inheritFromDir = search.luceneSearch('TYPE:"http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder" +@name:BulkCategorise +SITE:YOUR_SITE_NAME');
// We need to deref the array of noderefs result using inheritFromDir[0]
document.properties["cm:categories"] = inheritFromDir[0].properties["cm:categories"];
document.save();
```

The 2nd script is a bit more involved - we left the logging code in (commented out) for an example to see how to do that, because it took some time to figure out also (and is an extremely useful feature). As before update the @name and SITE on the first line to match your system.

```
var inheritFromDir = search.luceneSearch('TYPE:"http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder" +@name:AccumulateCategories +SITE:YOUR_SITE_NAME');
// We need to deref the single array result using inheritFromDir[0] to get categories from topmost parent (folder) node
var parentCatArray = inheritFromDir[0].properties["cm:categories"];
//and any existing categories of the doc, or null if none exist
var thisCatArray = document.properties["cm:categories"];
var thisLen = 0;

if (thisCatArray != null) {
   thisLen = thisCatArray.length;
} else {
   thisCatArray = new Array();
}

// Some logging to find out what  is going on...
//var logFile = space.childByNamePath("log.txt");

// If the log file does not already exist, create it in current folder.
//if (logFile == null) {
//    logFile = space.createFile("log.txt");
//}

//if (logFile != null) {
//    logFile.content += new Date().toGMTString() + "\tRun started. Length of existing array is: " + thisLen + "\r\n";
//    logFile.content += new Date().toGMTString() + "\tFound parent node categories:\r\n";
      for (var i=0; i < parentCatArray.length; i++)
      {
         thisCatArray[thisLen]=parentCatArray[i];
         thisLen += 1;
      }
//}

// Push the new array of categories to the document
thisCatArray.push(document);
// apply and save the doc
document.properties["cm:categories"] = thisCatArray;
document.save();
```

Et Voila! In a similar way we have implemented BulkTag and BulkAccumulateTags.  Now adding arbitrary categories is as simple as applying them to the folder and moving the content through with drag and drop.